# what is impact of shared logon uncheck in connection pool in OBIEE 11g?

Tags: obiee

What is the impact of shared logon uncheck in connection pool in OBIEE 11g?
e.g. one user deploy RPD using his/her credential unchecking shared logon on connection pool. What happen when other user try to run analytics report?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the shared logon then it'll use the username/password of the OBIEE user themselves, i.e. pass it through.

Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/conn_pool.htm#BHBCADGC

Answer (score 0):

Normally when Shared logon is enable from Connection Pool, you still need to define each user's credential.

You can define the credential under;
1.Oracle BI Administration tool
2.open the security manager (Manage> Security)
3.click on the user map
4.double click on a user
5.define in the tab logon the user credential for your database

Like moff stated, if one user deploys the RPD then unchecked the shared logon in the general tab of the connections pool, then each user will have to be authenticated using their own credential created in the Admin Console.

If the users are successfully able to connect to Analytics then they can run the report just fine.However you would have to disable query cached from the nqsconfig file.

Shared logon is not recommended for large organization.